# UI Automation for non-WPF or Win32 applications with C#

Tags: c#, ui-automation

In short: I want to use UI Automation in FL Studio 20 using C#. I know there are a lot UI automation frameworks out there. Currently, I'm using [Teststack.White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) but this framework is made for Win32, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight and SWT based applications. It works sort of for FL Studio 20. Here's what I mean:
[image: UI inspection]

The red rectangle is from a UI Inspection tool. And it is exactly what Teststack.White sees. It can make out the containers, but never the actual, clickable elements. Right now the only option I have left to click the button, is to get the location of the container and then simulate a mouse click with an offset. But that's only gonna work if the display resolution stays the same.

So my question is: Is there any framework that can handle these type of UI's? And does anyone know what GUI technology FL Studio is using? I know it's written in Delphi but that's all I know.

Here's the code that clicks the button using the offset-method I mentioned above (it's for a different button, but the code stays roughly the same):

```cs
TestStack.White.Application application = TestStack.White.Application.Launch(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Image-Line\FL Studio 20\FL.exe");
this.window = application.GetWindow("FL Studio 20", InitializeOption.NoCache);

UIItemCollection coll = window.Items;
Panel itemToClick = null;

foreach (UIItem item in coll)
{
    if (item.Name.Contains("Piano roll"))
    {
        if (((Panel)item).Items.Count == 0)
        {
            itemToClick = (Panel)item;
            break;
        }
    }
}

window.Focus();
var mouse = window.Mouse;
Point p = itemToClick.Location;
p.Offset(11, 12);
mouse.Click(p);
```